# getRingerMode () always returns a value of 0

Tags: android

I'm trying to determine the current ringer state by using the getRingerMode() method.

**I create a variable:** private int currentRingerMode;

**Set my variable to:** currentRingerMode = getRingerMode();

**And use a methods as follows:**
private int getRingerMode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return currentRingerMode;
    }

**But when I log the value of the variable with:**      Log.v(TAG, "value=" + currentRingerMode);

A value of 0 is always returned, regardless of the the ringer state...??? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

-Brian

---

-Update
Here is my current full code.

```
package com.DoNotDisturb.widget;
```

import com.DoNotDisturb.widget.R;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DoNotDisturbWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

```
private static final String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionRecieverWidget";
private static final String TAG = null;
private int currentRingerMode;
private int ringerMode;
private RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews("com.DoNotDisturb.widget", R.layout.main);  

private AudioManager getSystemService(String audioService) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;
    }


@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DoNotDisturbWidget.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_one, pendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);

    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Service.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
    int ringerMode = mAudioManager.getRingerMode();
    Log.d(TAG, "ringerMode value=" + ringerMode);

    ContextWrapper mContext = null;
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    currentRingerMode = manager.getRingerMode();
    Log.d(TAG, "ringerMode value=" + currentRingerMode);

}   



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)){

        Log.d(TAG, "ringerMode value=" + ringerMode);

        try {

            //Silent
            if(currentRingerMode == 2){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Silent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ((AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)).setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            Log.v(TAG, "After ButtonPress value=" + currentRingerMode);


            }

            //Vibrate
                if(currentRingerMode == 1){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Normal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ((AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)).setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                Log.v(TAG, "After ButtonPress value=" + currentRingerMode); 


                }

            //Normal Mode
            if(currentRingerMode == 0){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Silent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ((AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)).setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                Log.v(TAG, "After ButtonPress value=" + currentRingerMode); 

            }
        }

        finally{}

     }

    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `private int currentRingerMode;`, the default value of `currentRingerMode` is `0`.

And since you are calling `getRingerMode()` , apparently not from an `AudioManager` object, your method

```
private int getRingerMode() { 
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub return currentRingerMode; 
   return currentRingerMode;
}
```

is called, hence the `0` all the time

**UNTESTED**

So first, you have to retrieve the service for Audio

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

And from it, call the getRingerMode()

```
currentRingerMode = manager.getRingerMode();
```

**EDIT**
If you are inside an activity , the following should work

```
private int currentRingerMode;
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
currentRingerMode = manager.getRingerMode();
```

**EDIT 2**

In your `onUpdate`, try this

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DoNotDisturbWidget.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_one, pendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);

    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    currentRingerMode = manager.getRingerMode();
    Log.d(TAG, "ringerMode value=" + currentRingerMode);

}
```

Also , look at the LogCat and make sure you have the permission on AUDIO.

Comment: Also don't forget to set the required permissions to access the Audio service

Comment: Thanks for the response.

So if I understand it correctly, I still declare my variable in the same way like I did before, but my code should look like this?:

ContextWrapper mContext = null;
  AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  currentRingerMode = manager.getRingerMode();
  Log.d(TAG, "ringerMode value=" + currentRingerMode);

Thanks.

Comment: You are calling getSystemService from a mContext that is null (And I dont know the difference between ContextWrapper and a Context). You have to call it from a valid Context (for example an activity). Beside this, the rest is correct.

Comment: ok. So I guess I should be replacing mContext with a parameter that is not NULL? 

The strange thing is that this exact code works fine inside a regular application that I developed which uses a buttonReciever. But this is a widget using a pendingIntent which I guess makes a difference? Should I have to change anything because of that?

Comment: If by regular application, you mean activity, so yes, it works because an Activity is a valid context. If you add this for example the below code in a BroadcastReceiver, the onReceive methods is called with a context that you can use to call getSystemService. If you can, update your post with the code where the above should be run in (activity, broadcastereceiver or somethingelse)

Comment: Ok. I put my full code in my original post. 

As you can see, I tried executing the code in 2 ways, both of which do not work.

One using mContext and the other using just service and omitting Context.

Thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: Quick update. I got the code to execute successfully by moving it down to the onRecieve section and changing it slightly based on your suggestions:

AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  currentRingerMode = manager.getRingerMode();
  Log.d(TAG, "ringerMode value=" + currentRingerMode);

Thank you very much!!!!!